# Schema.org type for school lessons

Tags: schema.org

I've a bounch of school lessons (one per page) that I'd like describe with [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) (using *JSON-LD*).

The only type I've found suitable is `CreativeWork` but it seem too generic.

The available child-types of `CreativeWork` are:

> Article, Blog, Book, Clip, Code, Comment, CreativeWorkSeason, CreativeWorkSeries, DataCatalog, Dataset, Diet, EmailMessage, Episode, ExercisePlan, Game, Map, MediaObject, Movie, MusicComposition, MusicPlaylist, MusicRecording, Painting, Photograph, PublicationIssue, PublicationVolume, Question, Recipe, Review, Sculpture, Season, Series, SoftwareApplication, SoftwareSourceCode, TVSeason, TVSeries, VisualArtwork, WebPage, WebPageElement, WebSite

None of them fit the concept of a school lesson.

I've also thought about using a custom type, but I don't know how and if Google will accept it.

**EDIT** see @unor comment

About "*Google will accept it*".

I'd like to help Google to understand the quality of the content. My Fear is that using a custom type (eg Lesson) don't improve, or worst, will break the comprehension of the content.

My final goal is SEO, but improving SERP too will be nice.

Comment: Regarding your side question about if Google "will accept it": What exactly do you mean with "accept"? Currently Google only *does something* (e.g., showing a Rich Snippet on their SERP) for a very small subset of Schema.org (see https://developers.google.com/structured-data/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data about a specific school lesson (that was or will be held on a specific day), you could use an [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) type. [`EducationEvent`](http://schema.org/EducationEvent) seems to be the most-specific sub-type.

If you have data about the content for/of a school lesson (e.g., what gets taught), you could use a [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) type. If it’s in the form of an article, [`ScholarlyArticle`](http://schema.org/ScholarlyArticle) might be relevant.

Comment: ScholarlyArticle is a very interesting suggestion, and can be the type of some lessons.